# How to text extract from the logs

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract few lines from the log file.
It will have the same pattern so I am trying to extract all lines between them.

```
"FLOW:ReserveCapacitiesStep:PrecheckCapacity-X:belowMaxCapacityList: 4
Y918
Y251
Y887
X233
$onMaxCapacityList: 5
Y100
X069
Y010
Y400
Y401
$aboveMaxCapacityList: 0
overruledCapacityList: 0
reservedCapacities: 8
Y918
Y251
Y887
X233
X468
X081
X082
Y001
commonCapacities: 0
mandatoryCapacityList: 2
Y100
Y010
abort:false
"
```

I want data which exists between the $ $.

Please help me how I can do this using regex

Answer (score 2):

#### Using grep with GNU extensions

```
$ grep -ozP '[$][^$]*[$][^\n]*\n' logfile
$onMaxCapacityList: 5
Y100
X069
Y010
Y400
Y401
$aboveMaxCapacityList: 0
```

#### Using Python

```
$ python -c 'import re; print(re.search(r"[$][^$]*[$][^\n]*", open("logfile").read()).group())'
$onMaxCapacityList: 5
Y100
X069
Y010
Y400
Y401
$aboveMaxCapacityList: 0
```

#### Using sed:

```
$ sed -n '/^[$]/,/^[$]/p' logfile
$onMaxCapacityList: 5
Y100
X069
Y010
Y400
Y401
$aboveMaxCapacityList: 0
```

#### Using awk:

```
$ awk '/^[$]/{print; f=!f; next} f{print}' logfile
$onMaxCapacityList: 5
Y100
X069
Y010
Y400
Y401
$aboveMaxCapacityList: 0
```